# Iteration, calculation via pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

I am new in Python and I would like to ask something.

My code reads a csv file. I want to use one column. I want to use an equation which calculates, depending on the value of the column I want to use, several values. I am using commands for and if.

my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

dfArxika = pd.read_csv('AIALL.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], header=None, index_col=False)
print(dfArxika.columns)

A=dfArxika[9]

for i in A:
    if (A(i)>=4.8 and A(i)<66):
        IA=(2.2*log10(A(i)/66)+5.5)
    elif A(i)>=66:
        IA=3.66*log10(A(i)/66)+5.5
    else:
        IA=2.2*log10(A(i)/66)+5.5
```

but command window shbows me the error:

**TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable**

Could you help me?

Comment: `A(i)` is not how you index. It's `A[i]`

Comment: command window shows: TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [122.59] of <class 'float'>

Comment: You are iterating over the values of `dfArxika[9]` and using these to index your dataframe A. `dfArxika[9]`, contains floats, while the index of your dataframe `A` contains integers, that's why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

As @rdas mentioned in the comments, you are using parentheses `()` instead of brackets `[]` for indexing the values of your column.

I am not sure what`IA` is in your example, but this might work:

```
for i in range(len(dfArxika)):
    if (A.loc[i, 9]>=4.8 and A.loc[i, 9]<66):
        IA=(2.2*log10(A.loc[i, 9]/66)+5.5)
    elif A.loc[i, 9]>=66:
        IA=3.66*log10(A.loc[i, 9]/66)+5.5
    else:
        IA=2.2*log10(A.loc[i, 9]/66)+5.5
```